# search a node in a binary tree

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

i have this code that suppose seek the node in a binary tree:

```
def seekNode(self, node):
    if self.id == node:
        return self
    elif self.left != None:
        self.left.seekNode(node)      
    elif self.right != None:
        self.left.seekNode(node) 
    else:
        return False
```

but it returns a None object.

Here is the complete class:

```
class BinTree:
def __init__(self, id=None):
    self.id= id
    self.left= None
    self.right= None

def setId(self, id):
    if self.id == None:
        self.id= id
        return self
    else:
        return self.seekNode(id)

def addChildLeft(self, left):
    if self.left == None:
        self.left= BinTree(left)
    else:
        self.left.addChildLeft(left)

def addChildRight(self, right):
    if self.right == None:
        self.right= BinTree(right)
    else:
        self.right.addChildRight(right)

def seekNode(self, node):
    if self.id == node:
        return self
    elif self.left != None:
        self.left.seekNode(node)      
    elif self.right != None:
        self.left.seekNode(node) 
    else:
        return False
```

i only call setuId function, i debugged the code (i'm not expert doing this) and i saw that the function returned de object, but when i save this search, it turns in None object.
[image: Debug image in return statement]
[image: Debug image after return statement]

Comment: Your `elif self.right != None:
        self.left.seekNode(node)`  looks strange.

Comment: ohh, yeah u r right, but nevertheless, the code, in the case in i am trying, it is never executed, because i only add left childs.but i changed the code and stay with the same problem.

Comment: you are missing `return` keyword on several branches of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `return` before the recursive calls to `self.left.seek(...)` and `self.right.seek(...)`. The user of the tree also should not have to concern him/herself with `addLeft` or `addRight` - a simple `insert` method should automatically insert a new node in the proper location.

I would also point out recursion is a functional heritage and using it with functional style will yield the best results. This means avoiding things variable reassignment, other mutations, and side effects.

Let's see what it would look like to implement `btree` in this way -

```py
# btree.py

def empty():
  return None

def insert(t, v):
  if not t:
    return node(v)                                   # empty
  elif v < t.data:
    return node(t.data, insert(t.left, v), t.right)  # insert left
  elif v > t.data:
    return node(t.data, t.left, insert(t.right, v))  # insert right
  else:
    return t                                         # no change

def seek(t, v):
  if not t:
    return None             # no match
  elif v < t.data:
    return seek(t.left, v)  # seek left
  elif v > t.data:
    return seek(t.right, v) # seek right
  else:
    return t                # match
```

The data structure for `node` can be anything you want. Here's a dead-simple interface. Notice how the `left` and `right` properties can be set when a new node is constructed -

```py
class node:
  def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
    self.data = data
    self.left = left
    self.right = right
```